# Ocultar pantallas en java

Tags: java

Tengo una ventana emergente realizada en java que tiene 4 pantallas en las cuales debes dar siguiente para llegar hasta la 4ta pantalla,
entre la 2da pantalla y la 4ta hay una logica que si existe un certificado pase directo a la 4ta pantalla, si existe mas de un certificado habra la tercera pantalla que es la que permite seleccionar uno u otro,

Lo que quiero es ocultar la 1ra y 2da pantalla y que segun la logica de arriba se abra la 3ra pantalla si no derechamente la 4ta

el codigo es el siguiente

En esta parte se llama los metodo de cada pantalla

```
    initLoadDataPage();
    initSelectStoragePage();
    initSelectCertificatePage();
    initProcessDataPage();
```

y aca se añaden al panel content cada pantalla

```
    panelContent.add(pageLoadData, PAGE_NAME_LOAD_DATA);
    panelContent.add(pageSelectStorage, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_STORAGE);
    panelContent.add(pageSelectCertificate, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_CERTIFICATE);
    panelContent.add(pageProcessData, PAGE_NAME_PROCESS_DATA);

    layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_LOAD_DATA);
```

por ejemplo si comento el primer panelcontent no aparecera en pantalla pero aun asi se ejecutara su metodo y su codigo por detras

El tem es que hay un evento que se dispara que es el Next_click() que tiene la siguiente logica

```
private void buttonNextClick() {

        switch (currentPage) {

            case PAGE_LOAD_DATA:
                updateAppletParameters();
                updateSelectStorageControls();
                layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_STORAGE);
                currentPage = PAGE_SELECT_STORAGE;
                break;

            case PAGE_SELECT_STORAGE:
                signingKey = null;
                signingCert = null;
                certificates = null;

                if (!loadStorage())
                    return;

                if (bypassSelectCertificate) {
                    updateProcessDataControls();
                    currentPage = PAGE_PROCESS_DATA;
                    layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_PROCESS_DATA);
                    buttonNext.setText(BUTTON_FINISH);
                } else {
                    if (!loadCertificatesToTable())
                        return;
                    updateSelectCertificateControls();
                    currentPage = PAGE_SELECT_CERTIFICATE;
                    layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_CERTIFICATE);
                    buttonNext.setText(BUTTON_NEXT);
                }

                buttonBack.setEnabled(true);
                break;

            case PAGE_SELECT_CERTIFICATE:
                signingKey = null;
                signingCert = null;
                if (!loadCertificate())
                    return;
                updateProcessDataControls();
                currentPage = PAGE_PROCESS_DATA;
                layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_PROCESS_DATA);
                buttonNext.setText(BUTTON_FINISH);
                break;

            case PAGE_PROCESS_DATA:
                buttonBack.setEnabled(false);
                buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
                labelProgress.setVisible(true);
                labelProgressText.setVisible(true);
                processData();
                System.exit(0);

                break;
        }
    }
```

mi idea es poder simular el comportamiento del evento next derrepente lo hago llamando al metodo despues de que se llaman los metodos de las ventana pero la ventana carga mal, existe alguna funcion o metodo que deba utilizar?

edit: codigo completo

```
    public void init() {

    getAppletParameters();

    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initPanels();
            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void start() {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (loadData()) {
                buttonBack.setVisible(true);
                buttonNext.setVisible(true);
                buttonNext.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else {
                data = null;
                request = null;
                server = null;
            }
        }
    });

}

private void updateAppletParameters() {
    ArrayList<ElDCMessageParameter> parameters = request.getParameters();

    String newDataUrl = null, newGoUrl = null;

    for (ElDCMessageParameter param : parameters) {
        String name = param.getOID("utf-8");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "updateAppletParameters-> " + param);

        if (ElDCUtils.isEmpty(name))
            continue;

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PARAMETER_NAME_DATA_URL))
            newDataUrl = param.getValue("utf-8");
        else
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PARAMETER_NAME_GO_URL))
            newGoUrl = param.getValue("utf-8");
        else
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PARAMETER_NAME_SESSION_ID))
            sessionId = param.getValue("utf-8");
        else
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PARAMETER_NAME_TOKEN))
            tokenName = param.getValue("utf-8");
        else
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PARAMETER_NAME_ALLOW_WINDOWS_STORAGE))
            allowWindowsStorage = ElDCUtils.stringToBoolean(param.getValue("utf-8"), false);
        else
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PARAMETER_NAME_ALLOW_TOKEN_STORAGE))
            allowTokenStorage = ElDCUtils.stringToBoolean(param.getValue("utf-8"), false);
        else
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PARAMETER_NAME_ALLOW_FILE_STORAGE))
            allowFileStorage = ElDCUtils.stringToBoolean(param.getValue("utf-8"), true);
    }

    if (!ElDCUtils.isEmpty(newDataUrl) || !ElDCUtils.isEmpty(newGoUrl)) {
        dataUrl = newDataUrl;
        goUrl = newGoUrl;
    }

    ArrayList<ElDCMessageParameter> certInfo = request.getSigningCertInfo();

    if (certInfo != null) {
        signingCertInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (ElDCMessageParameter entry : certInfo) {
            String oid = ElDCUtils.base16Encode(entry.getOID());

            if (ElDCUtils.isEmpty(oid))
                continue;

            if (oid.equalsIgnoreCase(ElDCUtils.SB_OID_COMMON_NAME))
                signingCertInfo.put(ElDCUtils.CERT_ENTRY_COMMON_NAME, entry.getValue("utf-8"));
            else
            if (oid.equalsIgnoreCase(ElDCUtils.SB_OID_COUNTRY))
                signingCertInfo.put(ElDCUtils.CERT_ENTRY_COUNTRY, entry.getValue("utf-8"));
            else
            if (oid.equalsIgnoreCase(ElDCUtils.SB_OID_STATE_OR_PROVINCE))
                signingCertInfo.put(ElDCUtils.CERT_ENTRY_STATE_OR_PROVINCE, entry.getValue("utf-8"));
            else
            if (oid.equalsIgnoreCase(ElDCUtils.SB_OID_LOCALITY))
                signingCertInfo.put(ElDCUtils.CERT_ENTRY_LOCALITY, entry.getValue("utf-8"));
            else
            if (oid.equalsIgnoreCase(ElDCUtils.SB_OID_ORGANIZATION))
                signingCertInfo.put(ElDCUtils.CERT_ENTRY_ORGANIZATION, entry.getValue("utf-8"));
            else
            if (oid.equalsIgnoreCase(ElDCUtils.SB_OID_ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT))
                signingCertInfo.put(ElDCUtils.CERT_ENTRY_ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT, entry.getValue("utf-8"));
            else
            if (oid.equalsIgnoreCase(ElDCUtils.SB_OID_EMAIL_ADDRESS))
                signingCertInfo.put(ElDCUtils.CERT_ENTRY_EMAIL_ADDRESS, entry.getValue("utf-8"));
        }

        if (signingCertInfo.size() == 0)
            signingCertInfo = null;
    }
}

private void initPanels() {

    // replace the default applet layout with border layout

    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // create and insert the buttons panel

    initButtonsPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panelButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // create and insert the content panel

    layoutPages = new CardLayout();

    panelContent = new JPanel(layoutPages, false);
    getContentPane().add(panelContent);

    // create and insert the wizard pages

    initLoadDataPage();
    initSelectStoragePage();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita inicial");
    updateSelectStorageControls();
    //posicion 1
    initSelectCertificatePage();

    initProcessDataPage();


    //panelContent.add(pageLoadData, PAGE_NAME_LOAD_DATA);
    //panelContent.add(pageSelectStorage, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_STORAGE);
    //panelContent.add(pageSelectCertificate, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_CERTIFICATE);
    panelContent.add(pageProcessData, PAGE_NAME_PROCESS_DATA);

    layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_LOAD_DATA);



        try {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inicio delay!");      
         Thread.sleep(3000);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Finaliza delay!");        

     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "me cai poh!");        

     }
    buttonNextClick();

}

private void initLoadDataPage() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 1");     

    if (pageLoadData != null)
        return;

    pageLoadData = new JPanel(null, true);
    pageLoadData.setBackground(color);

    int y = 100;

    labelLoadStep = new JLabel("Loading data...");
    labelLoadStep.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelLoadStep.setBounds(10, y, 480, 14);
    pageLoadData.add(labelLoadStep);

    y += labelLoadStep.getHeight() + 10;

    labelRequestStatus = new JLabel("");
    labelRequestStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelRequestStatus.setBounds(10, y, 480, 20);
    labelRequestStatus.setVisible(false);
    pageLoadData.add(labelRequestStatus);

    y += labelRequestStatus.getHeight() + 10;

    labelRequestCertInfo = new JLabel("Signer: %s");
    labelRequestCertInfo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelRequestCertInfo.setBounds(10, y, 480, 14);
    labelRequestCertInfo.setVisible(false);
    pageLoadData.add(labelRequestCertInfo);
}

private void initSelectStoragePage() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 2");
    pageSelectStorage = new JPanel(null, true);
    pageSelectStorage.setBackground(color);

    int y = 0;

    JLabel label = new JLabel(translate("Step")+ "1." + translate("Select a certificate storage"));
    label.setBounds(10, y, 250, 14);
    pageSelectStorage.add(label);

    y += label.getHeight() + 12;

    label = new JLabel(translate("Signing certificate requested: (or "));
    label.setBounds(25, y, 190, 14);
    pageSelectStorage.add(label);

    checkUseOtherCertificate = new JCheckBox(translate("use other certificate)"));
    checkUseOtherCertificate.setOpaque(false);
    checkUseOtherCertificate.setBounds(label.getX() + label.getWidth(), y + 1, 150, 14);
    pageSelectStorage.add(checkUseOtherCertificate);

    y += label.getHeight() + 6;

    labelSigningCertInfo = new JLabel();
    labelSigningCertInfo.setBounds(25, y, 450, 14);
    labelSigningCertInfo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    pageSelectStorage.add(labelSigningCertInfo);

    y += labelSigningCertInfo.getHeight() + 20;

    radioWindows = new JRadioButton("Windows certificate storage");
    radioWindows.setBounds(25, y, 200, 14);
    radioWindows.setBackground(color);
    radioWindows.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            enableTokenStorageControls(false);
            enableFileStorageControls(false);
        }
    });
    pageSelectStorage.add(radioWindows);

    y += radioWindows.getHeight() + 12;

    radioToken = new JRadioButton(translate("Cryptographic token or smart card"));
    radioToken.setBounds(25, y, 250, 14);
    radioToken.setBackground(color);
    radioToken.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            enableTokenStorageControls(true);
            enableFileStorageControls(false);
        }
    });
    pageSelectStorage.add(radioToken);

    y += radioToken.getHeight() + 6;

    modelTokens = new TokensComboBoxModel();
    comboToken = new JComboBox(modelTokens);
    comboToken.setBounds(50, y, 270, 23);
    pageSelectStorage.add(comboToken);

    labelTokenPassword = new JLabel("PIN:");
    labelTokenPassword.setBounds(333, y + 2, 25, 14);
    pageSelectStorage.add(labelTokenPassword);

    textTokenPassword = new JPasswordField("");
    textTokenPassword.setBounds(360, y, 120, 23);
    labelTokenPassword.setLabelFor(textTokenPassword);
    pageSelectStorage.add(textTokenPassword);

    y += comboToken.getHeight() + 12;

    radioFile = new JRadioButton(translate("Certificate from a file"));
    radioFile.setBounds(25, y, 200, 18);
    radioFile.setBackground(color);
    radioFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            enableTokenStorageControls(false);
            enableFileStorageControls(true);
        }
    });
    pageSelectStorage.add(radioFile);

    y += radioFile.getHeight() + 6;

    labelFileName = new JLabel("File Name:");
    labelFileName.setBounds(50, y + 2, 60, 14);
    pageSelectStorage.add(labelFileName);

    textFileName = new JTextField("");
    textFileName.setBounds(116, y, 268, 23);
    labelFileName.setLabelFor(textFileName);
    pageSelectStorage.add(textFileName);

    buttonBrowse = new JButton("Browse...");
    buttonBrowse.setBounds(390, y, 90, 23);
    buttonBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            buttonBrowseClick();
        }
    });
    pageSelectStorage.add(buttonBrowse);

    JLabel labelFileNameNote = new JLabel("(leave the field empty to use the default Java Key Store)");
    labelFileNameNote.setEnabled(false);
    labelFileNameNote.setBounds(116, y + textFileName.getHeight() + 2, 320, 12);
    pageSelectStorage.add(labelFileNameNote);

    y = labelFileNameNote.getY() + labelFileNameNote.getHeight() + 6;

    labelFilePassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    labelFilePassword.setBounds(50, y + 2, 65, 14);
    pageSelectStorage.add(labelFilePassword);

    textFilePassword = new JPasswordField("");
    textFilePassword.setBounds(116, y, 200, 23);
    labelFilePassword.setLabelFor(textFilePassword);
    pageSelectStorage.add(textFilePassword);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(radioWindows);
    group.add(radioToken);
    group.add(radioFile);
    checkUseOtherCertificate.setSelected(true);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 3");
}

private void initSelectCertificatePage() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita intermedia");
    pageSelectCertificate = new JPanel(null, true);
    pageSelectCertificate.setBackground(color);

    int y = 0;

    JLabel labelCertificates = new JLabel("Step 2. Select a certificate to be used to sign the data");
    labelCertificates.setBounds(10, y, 320, 14);
    pageSelectCertificate.add(labelCertificates);

    y += labelCertificates.getHeight() + 10;

    tableModel = new CertificatesTableModel(columns);
    tableCertificates = new JTable(tableModel);
    tableCertificates.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    tableCertificates.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    tableCertificates.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    tableCertificates.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    // adjust "Expires On" column
    tableCertificates.getColumnModel().getColumn(COLUMN_EXPIRES_ON).setMaxWidth(100);               // reduce its max size
    DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    tableCertificates.getColumnModel().getColumn(COLUMN_EXPIRES_ON).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer); // align dates to the right
    // hide "Alias" column
    tableCertificates.removeColumn(tableCertificates.getColumn(tableModel.getColumnName(COLUMN_ALIAS)));
    // sort the table
    TableRowSorter<CertificatesTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<CertificatesTableModel>(tableModel);
    tableCertificates.setRowSorter(sorter);
    ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

    scrollerCertificates = new JScrollPane(tableCertificates);
    scrollerCertificates.setBounds(10, y, 480, 200);
    pageSelectCertificate.add(scrollerCertificates);

    y += scrollerCertificates.getHeight() + 6;

    labelKeyPassword = new JLabel("Certificate password:");
    labelKeyPassword.setBounds(10, y + 2, 130, 14);
    pageSelectCertificate.add(labelKeyPassword);

    textKeyPassword = new JPasswordField();
    textKeyPassword.setBounds(labelKeyPassword.getX() + labelKeyPassword.getWidth() + 2, y, 200, 23);
    labelKeyPassword.setLabelFor(textKeyPassword);
    pageSelectCertificate.add(textKeyPassword);
    radioWindows.setSelected(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita intermedia final");

}

private void initProcessDataPage() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita zero ini");

    pageProcessData = new JPanel(null, true);
    pageProcessData.setBackground(color);

    labelProcess = new JLabel(STEP_PROCESS_DATA);
    labelProcess.setBounds(10, 0, 270, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelProcess);

    JLabel labelCertificateTitle = new JLabel(translate("The data is to be signed with the following certificate:"));
    labelCertificateTitle.setBounds(50, 25, 300, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelCertificateTitle);

    JLabel labelSubject = new JLabel(translate("Issued To:"));
    labelSubject.setBounds(70, 53, 70, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelSubject);

    labelSubjectText = new JLabel("");
    labelSubjectText.setBounds(140, 53, 300, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelSubjectText);

    JLabel labelIssuer = new JLabel(translate("Issued By:"));
    labelIssuer.setBounds(70, 74, 70, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelIssuer);

    labelIssuerText = new JLabel("");
    labelIssuerText.setBounds(140, 74, 300, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelIssuerText);

    JLabel labelUrlInfo = new JLabel(translate("The signature will be sent to the following URL:"));
    labelUrlInfo.setBounds(50, 100, 300, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelUrlInfo);

    labelUrlText = new JLabel("");
    labelUrlText.setBounds(70, 125, 200, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelUrlText);

    JLabel labelReady = new JLabel(translate("Press \"Finish\" button to sign data and send the signature to the server."));
    labelReady.setBounds(50, 152, 420, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelReady);

    labelProgress = new JLabel(STEP_SEND_SIGNATURE);
    labelProgress.setBounds(10, 180, 100, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelProgress);
    labelProgress.setVisible(false);

    labelProgressText = new JLabel("");
    labelProgressText.setBounds(120, 180, 200, 14);
    pageProcessData.add(labelProgressText);
    labelProgressText.setVisible(false);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita zero final");
}

private void initButtonsPanel() {

    if (panelButtons != null)
        return;

    // create the panel

    panelButtons = new JPanel(true);
    panelButtons.setBackground(color);

    // create "Back" button

    buttonBack = new JButton(BUTTON_BACK);
    buttonBack.setEnabled(false);
    buttonBack.setVisible(false);
    buttonBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            buttonBackClick();
        }
    });
    panelButtons.add(buttonBack);

    // create "Next" button

    buttonNext = new JButton(BUTTON_NEXT);
    buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
    buttonNext.setVisible(false);
    buttonNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            buttonNextClick();
        }
    });
    panelButtons.add(buttonNext);
}

private void getAppletParameters() {

    color = getColor();

    dataUrl = getParameter(PARAMETER_NAME_DATA_URL);
    goUrl = getParameter(PARAMETER_NAME_GO_URL);
    sessionId = getParameter(PARAMETER_NAME_SESSION_ID);

    allowWindowsStorage = getBooleanParameter(PARAMETER_NAME_ALLOW_WINDOWS_STORAGE, true);
    allowTokenStorage = getBooleanParameter(PARAMETER_NAME_ALLOW_TOKEN_STORAGE, true);
    allowFileStorage = getBooleanParameter(PARAMETER_NAME_ALLOW_FILE_STORAGE, true);

    if (allowTokenStorage)
        tokenName = getParameter(PARAMETER_NAME_TOKEN);

}

private boolean getBooleanParameter(String paramName, boolean defaultValue) {
    return ElDCUtils.stringToBoolean(getParameter(paramName), defaultValue);
}

private Color getColor() {
    Color defaultColor = Color.WHITE;

    String s = getParameter(PARAMETER_NAME_COLOR);
    if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0))
        return defaultColor;

    if (s.charAt(0) == '#') {
        if (s.length() < 7)
            return defaultColor;

        try {
            int r = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1, 3), 16);
            int g = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3, 5), 16);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(5, 7), 16);

            return new Color(r, g, b);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return defaultColor;
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            return Color.decode(s);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return defaultColor;
        }
    }

}

private void buttonNextClick() {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 4 - " + currentPage);

    switch (currentPage) {


                case PAGE_LOAD_DATA:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 5 ");
                try{
                updateAppletParameters();
                updateSelectStorageControls();
                layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_STORAGE);
                currentPage = PAGE_SELECT_STORAGE;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 5.1 ");
}
        catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Me cai en el nect 1" + currentPage);
            buttonNextClick();
    }
        break;

        case PAGE_SELECT_STORAGE:
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 6");

            signingKey = null;
            signingCert = null;
            certificates = null;

            if (!loadStorage())
                return;

            if (bypassSelectCertificate) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 7");

                updateProcessDataControls();
                currentPage = PAGE_PROCESS_DATA;
                layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_PROCESS_DATA);
                buttonNext.setText(BUTTON_FINISH);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Banderita 8");

            } else {
                if (!loadCertificatesToTable())
                    return;
                updateSelectCertificateControls();
                currentPage = PAGE_SELECT_CERTIFICATE;
                layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_CERTIFICATE);
                buttonNext.setText(BUTTON_NEXT);
            }

            buttonBack.setEnabled(true);
            break;

        case PAGE_SELECT_CERTIFICATE:
            signingKey = null;
            signingCert = null;
            if (!loadCertificate())
                return;
            updateProcessDataControls();
            currentPage = PAGE_PROCESS_DATA;
            layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_PROCESS_DATA);
            buttonNext.setText(BUTTON_FINISH);
            break;

        case PAGE_PROCESS_DATA:
            buttonBack.setEnabled(false);
            buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
            labelProgress.setVisible(true);
            labelProgressText.setVisible(true);
            processData();
            System.exit(0);

            break;
      }

}
```

Comment: ¿es un applet amigo? si lo es puedes indicarme por favor si en él estas implementado el metodo init y el metodo start. Quedo atento a tus comentarios

Comment: Si amigo es un applet a priori puedo pegar el codigo completo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás revolviendo la lógica de cuando despliegas una página a cuando necesitas decidir que página sigue.

Yo haría una interface que cada página implementaría:

```
public interface Pagina {
  public void muestra();   //método para mostrar esta página
  public void next();      //método para decidir que página sigue
  public void before();    //método para irme a la página anterior.
```

}

y cambiaría este método:

```
private void buttonNextClick() {
        currentPage.next();
}
```

Te pongo un ejemplo, pero no conozco bien tus métodos.

```
public class PageNameLoadData implements Pagina {
     public void muestra() {
          updateAppletParameters();
          updateSelectStorageControls()layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_LOAD_DATA);
          buttonNext.setText(BUTTON_NEXT);
          buttonBack.setEnabled(false);
     }
     public void next() {
           pageSelectStorage.muestra();
     }
     public void before() {}
}

public class PageSelectStorage implements Pagina {
    public void muestra() {
       buttonBack.setEnabled(true);
      /*
        En este método pones lo que quieres que se ejecute aunque no se vaya
        mostrar, y si no quieres mostrar esta página entonces puedes, depediendo de tu lógica mostrar otra, por ejemplo:
      */
        if (bypassSelectCertificate) {
            pageNameProcessData.muestra();
       }
       else {
         ...
            layoutPages.show(panelContent, PAGE_NAME_SELECT_STORAGE);
            buttonNext.setText(BUTTON_NEXT);
      }
      public void next() {
         // Si estás ya en esta página y usuario da next, que página quieres mostrar?

      }
 }
```

Y así para cada página que tengas.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Estimado me parece muy bien su respuesta, a prior puedo editar la pregunta y dejar el código completo si eso ayuda a complementar su respuesta ya que es candidato a la recompensa

Comment: @PabloMoraga Me parece bien que edites tu pregunta para mejorar mi respuesta si así lo requieres. Saludos

Comment: listo amigo @AlbertoLopez

Comment: De acuero @PabloMoraga.  Dame tiempo porque quisiera revisarlo con calma y ando en el trabajo. Saludos

Comment: @PabloMoraga. Estuve revisando tu código editado, y sigo manteniendo mi respuesta inicial. Esto debido a que mi intención es mostrarte un esquema que pueda resolver tu necesidad.  El código que muestras está incompleto y complejo. Prefiero mantener mi respuesta y espero que te pueda servir para arreglar tu programa. Suerte!

Comment: una consulta, la interfaz va dentro de la misma clase? consulto ya que el codigo que te muestro se usa en mi pagina principal y cuando es llamada llama valga la redundancia los métodos de cada pagina

Comment: @PabloMoraga yo pondría la interfaz fuera de la clase buscando mantener la clase principal limpia. De hecho quizás implementaría cada página también fuera de la clase principal. Lo que busco es que mis clases tengan un solo propósito fácil de entender. Saludos